# Jsp, servlet back button issue

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, back-button

I am creating a simple website in Java EE, I am not using beans since I want to keep it simple.

The structure of website is like I have different Jsp pages and every jsp page has a corresponding servlet which then connects the jsp page to database to store and retrieve data.

The problem is that I have this one page index1 in which I select some option from drop down. My next jsp page which is index2.jsp should load data from the database in its fields according to the option selected from index1.jsp.

index2 has a next and previous button. I am storing the value of option selected from index1 to show on every jsp page just for now. However when I click next on this index2.jsp it takes me to index3 with the same option value but when I press previous button on index3 it takes me to the servlet of index2 which is Servlet2 in this case with the value of option being shown as NULL. It is destroying the value from the session when I press "previous" button. and after that all other pages show the value of option as null as well.

Another question is why the address of the servlet instead of indexa when loading data into indexa from the db using servlet.

Comment: From your description using beans would probably simplify your application.  Can you post some code?

Comment: Guess a proper code will do. Post it I can modify and tell you the answer.

Comment: Just updated the below as an answer by Farhan Ahmed.. Kindly check it.. waiting for quick response..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all without any code I'm kinda "answering in the dark"

**[...]every jsp page has a corresponding servlet which then connects the jsp page to database to store and retrieve data[...]**

Well, a JSP IS a servlet, so all your servlet code can be runned within the JSP but I'm assuming that you have chosen an MVC architecture.

I think your main problem is the following.

From index1.jsp you make a request to index2.jsp with the parameter called **param** (just an example).
Then in index2.jsp you make another request to index3.jsp with the same parameter called **param**
BUT when you hit previous you are not passing the parameter called **param** to index2.jsp

Either you pass the parameter back (safest) or you play with the browser's history (unsafe but will perform the SAME request that you made from index1.jsp to index2.jsp)

I'm afraid I can't help you anymore without any code

**EDIT**

I think this is your mistake
`request.setAttribute("corrtoepost", corrtoepost);`
you are not storing "corrtoepost" in **session** but in the request. To store a parameter in session you must do the following
`request.getSession().setAttribute("corrtoepost", corrtoepost);`

**NEW EDIT**
Ok, here is my fully functional example. I've tested it and it works.

indexA.jsp

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="servletA" method="POST">
            <select name="corrtoe">
                <%if("1".equals(request.getSession().getAttribute("corrtoe"))){ %>
                    <option value="1" selected>1</option>
                <%}else{ %>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                <%} %>
                <%if("2".equals(request.getSession().getAttribute("corrtoe"))){ %>
                    <option value="2" selected>2</option>
                <%}else{ %>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                <%} %>
                <%if("3".equals(request.getSession().getAttribute("corrtoe"))){ %>
                    <option value="3" selected>3</option>
                <%}else{ %>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                <%} %>
            </select>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

ServletA.java

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String corrtoepost = request.getParameter("corrtoe");
        //Search in DB or whatever
        request.getSession(true).setAttribute("corrtoe", corrtoepost);
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/indexB.jsp").forward(request,response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }
```

indexB.jsp

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1><%=request.getSession().getAttribute("corrtoe")%></h1>
        <form action="jsp/indexC.jsp" method="GET">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

indexC.jsp

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1><%=request.getSession().getAttribute("corrtoe")%></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is on my web.xml

```
<servlet>
   <display-name>servletA</display-name>
   <servlet-name>servletA</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.test.servlets.ServletA</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>servletA</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/servletA</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 <welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>jsp/indexA.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Please check my edit...I think you are failing to set the parameter into session.

Comment: I mean id does work on all other pages... but on indexb it shows null so basically when I press next on indexa.jsp which do get all the values from database and shows on interface through Servletnpro it disaapears the value in next index to 0!? do I have to pass value through url in next button or should it go automatically!? :S

Comment: Ok, I've posted a test solution.

Answer (score 0):

okay I will post all the code here alongwith description...

Okay here is code for first index called.. indexnpro.jsp which upon getting the values forwards them to Servletnpro like this..
`<form class="form-class" name="myform" action="Servletnpro" method="POST">` Note: remember since architecture here is MVC so every jsp will have its own servlet so values are not going direclty to another jsp but a servlet which then passes them to next jsp.....
Now in Servletnpro's dopost method...

```
String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/secnok?"+ "user=root&password=";
Connection connection=null;
response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
```

//these are different values I am getting from indexnpro.jsp, some of them are dropdown boxes but I shouldnt really matter..

```
String exproject=request.getParameter("country");
String corrcust=request.getParameter("state");
String excust=request.getParameter("country1" );
String corrproject=request.getParameter("state1");

String corrtoepost= request.getParameter("corrtoe");
```

<--------------- this value I keep on losing when pressing back button.. It changes to null when it comes back again to this servlet..

```
System.out.println(corrtoepost);

System.out.println("doPost is running");
System.out.println("Session id on dopost: " + session.getId() );
```

`request.setAttribute("corrtoepost", corrtoepost);` <--------------- storing value in session, still i keep on losing it..

/////////// From now is the simple code of database connectivity which will connect to database fetch the data based on user choice namely "corrtoepost" that I just stored in session.. and then will display it back on indexa.jsp ..

```
try{
int rs1;

// Load the database driver
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
// Get a Connection to the database
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL); 

//Add the data into the database

Statement stmt = connection.createStatement(); 
Statement stmt1 = connection.createStatement(); 
Statement stmt2 = connection.createStatement(); 
Statement stmt3 = connection.createStatement(); 
Statement stmt4 = connection.createStatement(); 
Statement stmt5 = connection.createStatement(); 
Statement stmt6 = connection.createStatement(); 





ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "Select * from toe_description where toe_id= '" + corrtoepost + "' " ) ;




ResultSet rs2 = stmt1.executeQuery( "Select * from toe_text where type_id=1 AND toe_id= '" + corrtoepost + "' " ) ;
ResultSet rs3 = stmt2.executeQuery( "Select * from toe_text where type_id=2 AND toe_id= '" + corrtoepost + "' " ) ;
ResultSet rs4 = stmt3.executeQuery( "Select * from toe_text where type_id=3 AND toe_id= '" + corrtoepost + "' " ) ;
ResultSet rs5 = stmt4.executeQuery( "Select * from toe_text where type_id=4 AND toe_id= '" + corrtoepost + "' " ) ;
ResultSet rs6 = stmt5.executeQuery( "Select * from toe_text where type_id=5 AND toe_id= '" + corrtoepost + "' " ) ;
ResultSet rs7 = stmt6.executeQuery( "Select * from toe_text where type_id=6 AND toe_id= '" + corrtoepost + "' " ) ;











while(rs.next()){
String toeid= rs.getString(1);
String toename= rs.getString(2);
String Intname= rs.getString(4);
String Assetname= rs.getString(5);
String Objname= rs.getString(6);
String ProjectID= rs.getString(7);



request.setAttribute("toeid", toeid);
request.setAttribute("toename", toename);
request.setAttribute("Intname", Intname);
request.setAttribute("Assetname", Assetname);
request.setAttribute("Objname", Objname);
request.setAttribute("ProjectID", ProjectID);





while(rs2.next()){
String purpose= rs2.getString(4);

request.setAttribute("purpose", purpose);








while(rs3.next()){
String scope= rs3.getString(4);

request.setAttribute("scope", scope);
System.out.println(scope);





while(rs4.next()){
String toe_desc= rs4.getString(4);

request.setAttribute("toe_desc", toe_desc);


System.out.println(toe_desc);




while(rs7.next()){
String toe_ass= rs7.getString(4);

request.setAttribute("toe_ass", toe_ass);








while(rs6.next()){
String enviroment= rs6.getString(4);

request.setAttribute("enviroment", enviroment);





while(rs5.next()){
String ass_env= rs5.getString(4);

request.setAttribute("ass_env", ass_env);



}


}



}



}



}



}

}


request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/indexa.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

// here I am sending all the data fetched from db to the required jsp which will then dislpay the data.. Namely "indexa.jsp"

```
System.out.println("Connected to the database"); 
connection.close();
System.out.println("Disconnected from database");

}

catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}



}



}
```

////////Now code Of Indexa.jsp

This page will show data fetched from Servletnpro discussed earlier..

Under body tag of page I retrieve that value of "corrtoepost" which I saved earlier in Servletnpro in a session.. I can see this value as of now..

```
String corrtoepost1=request.getParameter("corrtoepost"); 
String corrtoepost=(String) session.getAttribute("corrtoepost"); 
session.setAttribute("corrtoepost",corrtoepost);
```

and then display it on jsp page.. which is showing the right value as of now..

Now code for the next button in this page
Remember next button is suppose to take me to next page with same correcttoepost value which I got from servlet.

Next

Now lets go to next page which is indexb.jsp

Here I again get the value of "corrtoe" from indexa.jsp like this..

```
String corrtoe=(String) session.getAttribute("corrtoe"); 
session.setAttribute("corrtoe",corrtoe);
```

Uptill Now I am getting the right value even on this page... Problem Arises once I press back button on this page....

Now code for back button on this page..

Previous

Now when I press this previous button I lose the toe value in indexa.jsp page and it shows corrtoe value on interface as null..... After this I tried to use Servlets Get method to get the value which would work once but after pressing next on indexa.jsp it would show null on indexb.jsp and rest of the pages... Problem is that why am I losing this value when I am storing it in session as well.!!! Kindly give me some idea about....

Another question is that when I press submit on indexnpro page why does it shows Servletnpro in address bar instead of indexa.jsp ... However it does shows the page indexa.jsp populated with values from indexa.jsp... I think this is the reason why I keep on losing the "corrtoe" value between jsp pages..

Comment: this should be added to the question, not as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the question, it is about data storing across requests originating from index1 page value selection. There are multiple ways, one is keeping this value in session and using it across pages. Another is having hidden field on each screen and passing it across. This may be crude way. You can have single servlet and different methods for pages, or servlet to page mapping. Good to look at [JSP examples](http://www.deepakgaikwad.net/index.php/2009/04/13/java-server-pages-jsp-tutorial.html) for code samples.